# How can I use data augmentation for images with more than 3 channels?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I have `X_train` images of shape `[256, 256, 8]` and their corresponding `y_train` matrix with shape of `[256, 256]` as follows:

```
import numpy as np

X_train = [np.random.rand(256, 256, 8) for i in range(100)]
y_train = [np.random.randint(0, 5, size=[256, 256]) for i in range(100)]
```

I want to implement data augmentation like what [albumentations](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) does and generate some augmented data for training my deep learning model.

Currently, data augmentation libraries only use RGB images that have only 3 channels. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.